# vue-select v-model reduce not working / Nuxt js Vue js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-select

I'm using vue-select.
When I want to display the selected element, it shows me the value and not the text (see the screen).
I saw on several reports (and on the documentation) that I could use reduce.
I also saw that I could add a ":key" props on the component but that doesn't work either.

Here I choose the item :

[image]

Here the selected item, it displays the value and not the text : (Here the problem)

[image]

My component file (input-custom.vue) :

[image]

My component in page:
[image]

Data in page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

This is my "handleInput" method.

I emit "e.value" but I want to emit the Object, so replace "e.value" => "e"